# Unix get final directory name in a symlink

Tags: shell, unix, directory, symlink

I have symlinks in a directory full of versions that each point to a specific version.
The file structure would look like this:

- /path/to/stuff/v1
- /path/to/stuff/v1.1
- /path/to/stuff/v2
- /path/to/stuff/v3
- /path/to/stuff/A -> /path/to/stuff/v1.1
- /path/to/stuff/B -> /path/to/stuff/v3

I need a way to get only the version number from a specific symlink (i.e for /path/to/stuff/A I want only "v1.1").

readlink gets the whole path: readlink /path/to/stuff/A = /path/to/stuff/v1.1

I've scoured other questions but nothing I've found has met these exact requirements yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `basename` with [command
substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) (available in all POSIX shells, not only in Bash):

```
$ basename "$(readlink /path/to/stuff/A)"
v1.1
```

Or `rev` + `cut`:

```
$ readlink  /path/to/stuff/A | rev | cut -d/ -f1 | rev
v1.1
```

Comment: Top example works perfectly! doesn't seem to require quotes though

Comment: Quotes are needed to prevent  [word
splitting](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/wordsplitting), it's a good practice to always them unless you're know what you're doing. Try with path that contains whitespace for example